# How do I print this out in a orderly format in Python

Tags: python, printing

[Print Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoo6A.png)    --- Output Image

The length of the second line is increased as it has more characters, how can i maintain a constant space, i have something like this to print in a for loop

```
for i in range(0,len(arp_table)):
    print(arp_table[i].interface_name+"         "+arp_table[i].ip_address+"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [formatting specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) string.

You didn't give a complete example of your situation, so I have to presume the structure of your data:

```
class Arp_entry:
    def __init__(self, interface_name, ip_address, mac):
        self.interface_name = interface_name
        self.ip_address = ip_address
        self.mac = mac

arp_table = [
    Arp_entry("em1.0", "128.0.0.16", "00:0c:29:38:fa:60"),
    Arp_entry("ge-0/0/0.0", "172.17.1.2", "00:0c:29:74:6b:a6"),
    Arp_entry("ge-0/0/1.0", "172.17.3.2", "00:0c:29:74:6b:b0"),
    Arp_entry("fxp0.0", "192.168.0.16", "b8:27:eb:45:b8:30"),
    Arp_entry("fxp0.0", "192.168.0.22", "4c:32:75:96:72:eb"),
    Arp_entry("fxp0.0", "192.168.0.23", "00:0c:29:af:f0:a5"),
    Arp_entry("fxp0.0", "192.168.0.24", "00:0c:29:cc:a8:c3")
    ]

formatting_string = "{0:<25}{1:<25}{2:<30}"

print(formatting_string.format("INTF", "IP_ADDRESS", "MAC"))
print(formatting_string.format("----", "----------", "---"))

for current_entry in arp_table:
    print(formatting_string.format(current_entry.interface_name,
                                   current_entry.ip_address,
                                   current_entry.mac))
```

Comment: Thank you, you have understood the requirement just fine, i will give this a try and will let you know